# Is it possible to combine 2 view models, each populated with 2 different LINQ queries and return to 1 view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am trying to display 2 sets of data in 1 view:

**First LINQ:**

```
var result = from add in db.Addresses
                     join u in db.Users on add.UserID equals u.Id
                     where CurrUser == add.UserID
                     select new AddressViewModel
                     {
                        FirstAddressLine = add.FirstAddressLine,
                        SecondAddressLine = add.SecondAddressLine,
                        Town = add.Town,
                        PostCode = add.PostCode,
                        Distance = addDis
                     };
```

**Second LINQ:**

```
var result = from c in db.Carts
                     join s in db.Sweets on c.SweetID equals s.SweetID
                     where c.CartID == cartId
                     select new ShoppingCartViewModel
                     {
                         SweetName = s.SweetName,
                         Qty = c.Qty,
                         Price = s.Price,
                         SweetTotal = (s.Price * c.Qty),
                         Singular = s.Singular,
                         CartTotal = cartTotal
                     };
```

The 2 view models are the following:

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    public string FirstAddressLine { get; set; }
    public string SecondAddressLine { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Distance { get; set; } 
}

public class ShoppingCartViewModel
{
    public decimal? CartTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal? SweetTotal { get; set; }
    public bool? Singular { get; set; }              
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public int? RecordID { get; set; }
    public string CartID { get; set; }
    public int? SweetID { get; set; }
    public int? PemixID { get; set; }
    public int? Qty { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string SweetName { get; set; }
}
```

But I am not sure on what the best practice is for returning 2 view models into 1?

Edit: Apologise if I am missing the obvious (still learning) but I am not sure how to follow your answers... I have created a partial view of the shopping cart: **_ShoppingCartPartial** which I have placed in the shared views folder.

When I attempt to render the partial view in the Checkout view I receive the error that it is expecting **ShoppingCartViewModel** but I am currently sending it the **AddressViewModel**.

I have made a viewmodel of the both:

```
 public class CheckoutViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Address> AVM { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Cart> SCVM { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is I am not sure what i Should be changing my controller (below) to:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var CurrUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var addDis = getAddDis(CurrUser);

        var result = from add in db.Addresses
                     join u in db.Users on add.UserID equals u.Id
                     where CurrUser == add.UserID
                     select new AddressViewModel
                     {
                        FirstAddressLine = add.FirstAddressLine,
                        SecondAddressLine = add.SecondAddressLine,
                        Town = add.Town,
                        PostCode = add.PostCode,
                        Distance = addDis
                     };


        return View(result);
    }
```

Comment: you have to add both ViewModels in another single ViewModel

Comment: Use 1 View with 2 Partials: 1 view to hold the partials.  2 partials for your data.  Pass the (concrete) view models into each - @{ Html.RenderPartial("your view", your_model, ViewData);}

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a partial for your ADDRESS
2. Create a partial for your SHOPPING CART

Place them into your view...

```
@model Something.Models.MyMainViewModel
<div>
    <div>
         @Html.Partial("~/Views/MyMain/AddressPartial.cshtml", Model.Address)
    </div>
    <div>
         @Html.Partial("~/Views/MyMain/ShoppingCartPartial.cshtml", Model.ShoppingCart)
    </div>
</div>

public class MyMainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region <Constructors>

    public MyMainViewModel(IApplication application, int id) : base(application)
    {
        Address = Application.GetAddress(id); //<-- From the base class
        ShoppingCart = Application.GetShoppingCart(id); //<-- From the base class
    }

    #endregion

    #region <Properties>

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public ShoppingCart ShoppingCart { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class MainViewController : BaseController
{
    #region <Actions>

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DoSomething(int id)
    {           
        var viewModel = new MyMainViewModel(application, id);

        return View("MyView", viewModel);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class ViewModelBase
{
    #region <Constructors>

    public ViewModelBase(IApplication application)
    {
        Application = (MyApplication)application;
    }

    #endregion

    #region <Properties>

    protected MyApplication Application { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

**SIDE NOTES:**
Consider moving all your Linq queries into your business layer & having your presentation layer simply "talk to" the business (application) layer.  This is MUCH cleaner, it makes the application more "portable" & improves testability.

- The only caveat to this is when the Linq query is specific to the presentation layer...but honestly...that should be rare.

Comment: in fact you do not HAVE to use two partial views... you can use your "MainViewModel" in a single view without any partial view. but of course, the code would be more clean with partial view

Answer (score 0):

Have a main view model that contains both child view models.  Something like this would work:

```
    public class SomePageViewModel
    {
        private IAddressService _addressService;
        private IShoppingCartService _shoppingCartService;

        public SomePageViewModel(
            IAddressService addressService,
            IShoppingCartService shoppingCartService)
        {
            _addressService = addressService;
            _shoppingCartService = shoppingCartService;
        }

        public async Task GetDataAsync()
        {
            Address = await _addressService.GetAddressViewModelAsync();
            ShoppingCart = await _shoppingCartService.GetShoppingCartAsync();
        }

        public AddressViewModel Address { get; private set; }

        public ShoppingCartViewModel ShoppingCart { get; private set; }
    }
```

Your LINQ statements would be contained in the `IAddressService` and `IShoppingCartService` (or perhaps you'd call directly into respositories), respectively.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single view model that contains the two other view models:

```
public class FullViewModel {
    public AddressViewModel AddressModel { get; set; }
    public ShoppingCartViewModel ShoppingCartModel { get; set; }
}
```

And then just return that model.

From there you just need to create two partials:

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("[path]", Model.AddressModel)
    @Html.Partial("[path]", Model.ShoppingCartModel)
</div>
```